# Why use @model IQueryable<> in the Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using @model IQueryable<> in the Razor View is a good idea ? Any suitable scenario will you use @model IQueryable<> in the Razor View ? I just replaced IQuerable<> with List<> from Legacy codes. There is no elder developer in the company to ask of.

```
@model IQueryable<T>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Sn</th>
        <th>Kind</th>
    </tr>
    @{
        var count = 1;
    }
    @using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn_delKind btn btn-danger" data-kind-id="@item.id">Delete</button>
                </td>
                <td>@count</td>
                <td>
                    @switch (item.Type)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            @Html.Raw("All")
                            break;
                        default:
                            @Html.Raw(db.LookupType.Find(item.Type).Name)
                            break;
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
</table>
```

Before Edit:
My previous point of views,

1. <del>Costs larger memory (Resource concern)</del>
2. The way to manipulate model will rely on server side, hard to transfer to frontend javascript. (Separation of concern)
3. Very likely generates more C# LINQ codes surrounding by HTML. Not a simple, static, well-structureed object to use for rendering. <del>(Performance concern)</del>

---

After collect comments and answers (thanks for those)

1. unexpected memory usage
2. unexpected query counts
3. violation of the MVC pattern

Comment: why do you think IQueryable uses more ram than List? in fact it could be using less

Comment: Why does it use `IQueryable<T>` at all? `IQueryable` is for representing database queries, so the view might be actually doing a whole lot more than it is supposed to

Comment: It's probably just there because someone was being lazy or didn't understand what they were doing. Also side note; instead of going through all the effort of blurring out the screenshot you could have just used a code block and made a class name up. Screenshots for code are forbidden on SO.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using entity framework here.  The IQueryable won't keep a connection.  All the connection management is held in the DbContext.  it will open and close the connection as needed.  That being said, your context could be disposed of by the time someone wants to execute that query in the view.

Comment: @Fran Thanks to remind of that. You are right as well as Steve's post earlier. And also means you'll using this way somewhere ?

Comment: this sounds like violation of the MVC pattern.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I just removed the screenshot, pasting the whole code block. Try follow the rule and better code presentation.

Comment: I was making the assumption a controller action was performing all your data access and you were passing a viewmodel back to the view.  but the dbcontext was added to the view to get a lookuplist?  why isn't this just returned in the viewmodel or at worst pushed into the ViewBag in the controller action?

Comment: @Fran I did similar refactor as yours. Agree with you. Cus the previous version sounds really wired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question - **no, there is no reason for using `IQueryable<T>` in view**.

Whole purpose of `IQueryable<T>` is to provide mechanism, that allows you to write C# code, which can be translated to some other form understandable by other programs/tools. In this case, assuming you're using Entity Framework, `IQueryable<T>` interface defines methods, that allows Entity Framework to transform your query from C# to SQL. This can be done using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees). Using expression trees is the main difference between `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

It's not true, that `IQueryable` uses more memory than `IEnumerable`. With `IEnumerable` you keep your objects in memory, so you have to allocate space for every object in your collection. `IQueryable` defines interface for **querying** data, so you don't need to store anything in memory.

In your view you need to be able to iterate through your collections and display specific set of data. To do that methods provided by `IEnumerable` are more than enough. Using `IQueryable` in your view won't do anything good for you, but might cause a lot of problems, as was already mentioned in comments.

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks for explanation. I think foreach (var item in Model) cause a real query and will get result in List<T>, which costs same ram as my newer version. Btw, IEnumerable<T> is supposed to another topic.

Comment: @Kevin That depends. Do two `foreach` on `Model` and you will be duplicating the query on the DB server and hence duplicating the items in RAM, so it's not an easy problem

Comment: I think so, too. It depends.